# Javascript issues, need to color values inside table based on selection from 2 <select>

Tags: javascript, css

i want to color parts of a table based on the selection in 2 menus, as in, i want to color the selected values, and the ones between.

The whole table is green, and i want to put red on the selected values and everything between them.

I am having issues getting it to work, if anyone could take a look and give me a hint, it would be great.

http://jsfiddle.net/fqwvy/1/

I think the issue lies in my function... the

```
function placeColor();
```

Comment: It's failing on this line: var from_color = theForm.elements["from_color"];     I see you are trying to use jquery at the end.  Why not use it for the rest of the javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var picked_time = {}; // make array for current level price
```

{ } does not create an array in javascript, but rather an object. Use [ ]